# import projects in build path for web service: server or client?

Tags: web-services, codenameone, buildpath

I have created a little example app to test out the CN1 web service functionalities. Following the web service tutorial from CN1 (https://www.codenameone.com/how-do-i---access-remote-webservices-perform-operations-on-the-server.html), I have my Codename one project as client and a dynamic web project running on my Eclipse tomcat server hosting the servlet.

As I have objects that I pass back and forth between client and server, I want both projects to know about these java files. The way to do that is to put the file in one project, and modify the build path of the other to include the first project. This way, the import can resolve the file name just fine.

Question now is: is it better to put the files in one project or the other? Does either way affect the size of the resulting app file that I want to publish in a store? I want to keep the size as small as possible.

Thanks for any tips.

UPDATE: on the preliminary information provided by Shai, files that are to be shared among different projects (either client or server side), do not put your code in either but INSTEAD create a CN1 library for that. This library can then be added to the CN1 buildpath configuration (not the Java build path!) to all required projects. 
Here are the details on how and why: https://www.codenameone.com/blog/new-preliminary-library-support.html

Just need to figure out how to do this on Eclipse, as it does not seem to be supported now.

Answer (score 0):

You can use shared code with a cn1lib whose source you can include into the server project manually. In some cases we just copy the shared source files in the build script from one project to the other as it makes the process simpler.

Comment: Hi Shai,
I now went ahead by having the code in the server project and adjusting the Java build path of the client project. This works within Eclipse, even though CN1 delivers multiple build errors that the files are unknown. I assume the Java and the CN1 build path are different?

1. Can I somehow adjust CN1 build.xml to be aware of another project I included in the Java build path?

2. how would I go about using the shared code cn1lib that you mentioned?

Comment: The simulator is based on Java SE so it will work but will fail for the device. That's why we limit the classpath as we can't support the full Java API on devices without sacrificing a lot. I explained this in this blog post: https://www.codenameone.com/blog/why-we-dont-support-the-full-java-api.html

Comment: Ok, I got why you do not support JARs now and I also saw that link about how to use CN1 libs (https://www.codenameone.com/blog/new-preliminary-library-support.html). Which is what I should have done all along.

However, the libs are not available to be created in Eclipse. Is there an easy workaround for that? I guess its not as simple as zipping my java files up and renaming them to .cn1lib?

Comment: You can use the Extension Manager tool in Codename One Settings to install cn1libs now which is much easier. The cn1libs are generally just Ant projects you can look at any one of them on the cn1libs page and just use it as a starting template in Eclipse. You can browse through them on the web here: https://www.codenameone.com/cn1libs.html

Comment: Ok, hopefully the last question. I used the extension manager to browse through the list of available cn1libs, downloaded one and used "refresh cn1libs" to get it working. So far so good.
However, I would need to add my own library, existing of a few java files without any dependencies.
The only way to get this started is to use NetBeans IDE to create a fresh cn1lib, correct? using a downloaded cn1lib as a template did not work for me, as the .cn1lib opens as gibberish within Eclipse and is unreadable.

Comment: No you need to use the source code of the cn1lib. Notice that when you go to the list of extensions most of them point to their respective github project page. A cn1lib project is basically an ant project. When you build it and generate a cn1lib it's a zip file containing other zip files, you can place it in the lib directory of your eclipse project and use refresh libs to install it.